# H1 tag not showing on front page

Tags: theming, wysiwyg

Im using Drupal 7.41 and Omega3 sub theme and Ckeditor. I have added a sentence in the style of heading (h1)  at the top of my Home Page content, it shows in Ckeditor using the source button (showing markups) with H1 tags around the heading, and shows in the style of H1 normally in Ckeditor. When I save and close off the edit, it just appears as normal text, and as P tags when I view via Firefox (View Source) , the H1 markup is not showing, when I go back into Ckeditor, I can see its in the style of H1 and when I click Source button,  i can see it has the H1 tags around it. When I View Source on Firefox, it shows as P tags. I have flushed Cache, and checked but it still shows as P tags.

Basically, its showing correctly in Ckeditor (with/without clicking Source button), the markup is not getting wiped, but its just not showing when I view the webs page when I come out of Ckeditor (either logged in or not). Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you use filter html or a custom one? Check the settings of the html you're using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to:

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Advanced (for Filter HTML)

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full (for Full HTML)

Then under Advanced Content Filter, select disabled.

[image]

**If the above does not do it**, depending on which one you are using (filter or custom) You need to go to

/admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html

#### **add the `<h1>` to the limit allowed html list**

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. I had disabled everything in CKeditor, but not allowed the H1 tag in Content / Formats. all working fine now after flushing cache.